# Creating a tensorflow Variable without setting the initial value

Tags: tensorflow, initialization

I'm learning Tensorflow these days.

When we create a Tensor using tf.Variable, the first argument is "initial_value". So, even if we don't have specific values as initial values in mind, this value must be given.

The following is an example:

```
a = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 200]), name="a")
```

I think in some cases, we do not want to set the initial values, since the variable will be evaluated later as shown below:

```
a = c + e  # where "c" and "e" are some Tensor variables.
```

My question is in the above case, initializing the above `a` using `tf.zeros([784, 200])` is completely waste of computation. What would be the best practice in such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there's a well-defined best practice here, but I agree that building a tensor just to define a shape is wasteful. A better approach is to avoid initializing `a` explicitly altogether. The trick here is to remember that TensorFlow operations return `tf.Tensor` objects. The shape of those tensors is determined by the tensors input to the operation, and the operations effect on those tensors. For example, `z = tf.add(x, y)` takes two tensors and returns a third tensor with the same shape.

```
import tensorflow as tf

c = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]])
e = tf.constant([[1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0]])

# Here I define a via operator overload. Note, no initialization.
a = c + e

sess = tf.Session()

# Now, evaluate a in the session. Still no intitializtion.
a_out = sess.run(a)

print(a_out)
```

This is answer is probably a bit unsatisfying, because you still want a `tf.Tensor` of a particular shape for `a`. The way you specify the shape is through your graph architecture. This architecture starts with the `tf.placeholder` nodes in your graph (you can find more information [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder)). These require you to specify a shape, and those shapes are the foundational shapes in your graph.

Hope this is helpful!